# Python Converting a sorted dictionary to list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists

```
L1 = ['tom', 'jerry', 'spike', 'fido', 'donald', 'mickey']
L2 = [3,5,7,6,9,3]
dictionary = dict(zip(L1, L2))
print dictionary

sorted_friends = sorted(dictionary.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse= True)
print sorted_friends
```

Basically, I am creating a dictionary from L1 and L2.
     `{'mickey': 3, 'tom': 3, 'jerry': 5, 'donald': 9, 'fido': 6, 'spike': 7}`
Sorting (reverse) sorting it by value, which gives me:`[('donald', 9), ('spike', 7), ('fido', 6), ('jerry', 5), ('mickey', 3), ('tom', 3)]`

I want a list of the top 3 keys: like `[donald,spike,fido]`
But the problem is if I use any method that I know like casting to dict() etc its spoiling the sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use a dict; just create the list of tuples and sort them by the appropriate field.

```
sorted(zip(L1, L2), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
```

You can of course use `operator.itemgetter(1)` instead of the lambda, as you please.

If you just want the names after the fact, you can modify this:

```
[a for a,_ in sorted(zip(L1, L2), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)][:3]
```

---

Note that you could also conveniently avoid having to specify a custom sort function at all by simply reversing the order:

```
[b for _,b in sorted(zip(L2, L1), reverse=True)][:3]
```

This works because the default sort order for tuples sorts them according to their first element, then their second, and so on - so it will sort by the values first.

Comment: ``operator.itemgetter()`` is better than a lambda here.

Comment: Also, you'll need to use the `reversed` flag in the sort. Right now, you're getting the 3 smallest

Comment: @Lattyware Depends. For a quick one-off, it's an extra import and a lot longer. For large datasets, yes, it might be slightly faster, but for small sets, the difference is negligible.

Comment: @Amber thanks a lot this works like magic. Actually, my set could be large and if I wish to use operator.itemgetter() then would thsi be correct sorted(zip(L1, L2), key=operator.itemgetter(1) x: x[1])[:3]

Comment: No, just `key=operator.itemgetter(1)`. The `lambda x:x[1]` part is the equivalent of the itemgetter call.

Comment: @Amber Thanks I guessed and tried it myself it worked. Now my output looks like [('donald', 9), ('spike', 7), ('fido', 6)] I want it to look like [donald,spike,fido]. Sorry for bothering on a sunday night :-)

Comment: you can just get the first item from each tuple like so: `[name for (name, number) in results]`, where results is what you get from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the 3 largest, why not just use [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)?

```
>>> L1 = ['tom', 'jerry', 'spike', 'fido', 'donald', 'mickey']
>>> L2 = [3,5,7,6,9,3]
>>> dictionary = dict(zip(L1, L2))
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
['donald', 'spike', 'fido']
```

It's also possible, but a little tricky to skip creating the dictionary

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, L1, key=lambda x, i2=iter(L2): next(i2))
['donald', 'spike', 'fido']
```